# Where does the reducer get the state from?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to understand redux with the help of an online todo application resource.
However, I can't seem to figure out where does the 'todos' reducer get the initial state from ?
I've consoled the state but can't seem to wrap my head around it ?
After the initial render, state is consoled 3 times as,

1. [ ]
2. [ ]
3. [ state object ]

Link: 'https://codepen.io/iamrkcheers/pen/rNNoBvB'

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You.

```
// --------- actions start  ----------

const ADD_TODO = "ADD_TODO";
const TOGGLE_TODO = "TOGGLE_TODO";
const SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER = "SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER";
const VisibilityFilters = {
  SHOW_ALL: "SHOW_ALL",
  SHOW_COMPLETED: "SHOW_COMPLETED",
  SHOW_ACTIVE: "SHOW_ACTIVE"
};

let nextTodoId = 3;

function addTodo(text) {
  return {
    type: ADD_TODO,
    id: nextTodoId++,
    text
  }
}

function toggleTodo(id) {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_TODO,
    id
  }
}

function setVisibilityFilter(filter) {
  return {
    type: SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER,
    filter
  }
}

// --------- actions end  ----------

// --------- reducers start  ----------

function todos(state = [], action) {
  console.log('state is:',state);
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TODO: {
      return [...state, {
        text: action.text,
        completed: false,
        id: action.id
      }];
    }

    case TOGGLE_TODO: {
      return state.map((todo, id) => {
        if (id === action.id) {
          return Object.assign({}, todo, {
            completed: !todo.completed
          });
        }

        return todo;
      });
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}

function visibilityFilter(state = VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER: {
      return action.filter;
    }

    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}

const todoApp = Redux.combineReducers({
  visibilityFilter,
  todos
});

// --------- reducers end  ----------

// --------- components start  ----------

const App = () => {
  const getDate = date => new Date(date);
  const days = ["Воскресенье", "Понедельник", "Вторник", "Среда", "Четверг", "Пятница", "Суббота"];

  return (
    <div className="block">
      <div className="info-date">
        <div className="date">{ getDate(Date.now()).toLocaleDateString("ru") }</div>
        <div className="day">{ days[getDate(Date.now()).getDay()] }</div>
      </div>
      <AddTodo />
      <Footer />
      <VisibleTodoList />
    </div>
  );
};

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div className="filters">
      <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ALL">Все задачи</FilterLink>
      <FilterLink filter="SHOW_ACTIVE">Активные</FilterLink>
      <FilterLink filter="SHOW_COMPLETED">Завершенные</FilterLink>
    </div>
  );
};

const Link = ({ active, children, onClick }) => {
  if (active) {
    return <span className="filter-item non-active">{ children }</span>
  }

  return (
    <a className="filter-item" href="#" onClick = { event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        onClick();
      } }>{ children }</a>
  );
};

const Todo = ({ onClick, completed, text }) => {
  const styles = {
    textDecoration: completed ? "line-through" : "none"
  };

  return (
    <li onClick = { onClick } style = { styles }>
      <a>{ text }</a>
    </li>
  );
};

const TodoList = ({ todos, onTodoClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="list">
      <ul>
        {
          todos.map(todo => <Todo
            key = { todo.id } { ...todo }
            onClick = { () => onTodoClick(todo.id) } />)
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

// --------- components end  ----------

// --------- containers start  ----------

let AddTodo = ({ dispatch }) => {
  let input;

  return (
    <div>
      <form className="addForm" onSubmit = { event => {
          event.preventDefault();

          if (!input.value.trim()) {
            return;
          }

          dispatch(addTodo(input.value));

          input.value = "";
        } }>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Что нужно сделать?" ref = { node => input = node }/>
        <button type="submit" className="btn"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

AddTodo = ReactRedux.connect()(AddTodo);

var mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    active: ownProps.filter === state.visibilityFilter
  };
};

var mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    onClick: () => {
      dispatch(setVisibilityFilter(ownProps.filter));
    }
  };
};

const FilterLink = ReactRedux.connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Link);

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case "SHOW_ALL": {
      return todos;
    }

    case "SHOW_COMPLETED": {
      return todos.filter(todo => todo.completed);
    }

    case "SHOW_ACTIVE": {
      return todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed);
    }

    default: {
      return todos;
    }
  }
};

var mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
};

var mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: id => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id));
    }
  };
};


const VisibleTodoList = ReactRedux.connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList);

// --------- containers end  ----------

// --------- application start  ----------

const initialState = {
  visibilityFilter: "SHOW_ALL",
  todos: [
    {
      id: 0,
      text: "Изучить React",
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      text: "Изучить Redux",
      completed: true
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: "Написать приложение \"Список задач\"",
      completed: false
    }
  ]
};

let store = Redux.createStore(todoApp, initialState);

ReactDOM.render(
  <ReactRedux.Provider store = { store }>
    <App />
  </ReactRedux.Provider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);

// --------- application end  ----------
```

Comment: Are you looking for an answer that describes data flow in a React app?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the initial state right here :

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
```

Generally, while defining reducers, we also define `initialState`(`state = [] in your case`) , which is the state that goes into the reducer till we populate it with data (from an external source like api, or user input).

You can read more on initial state here : https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state#initializing-state

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways where you can define initial state;
the first one is in your reducer where you did function
`todos(state = [], action)`  and , 
the second is when you create the store, you can pass initial state as a second argument in your createStore function. In your case , you have a second argument when you create your store which is an array of three todos which you can see when you console log it. `store = Redux.createStore(todoApp, initialState)`, here the reducer gets this initial state